# custom UITableView ScrollView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scrollview

Good time of day, i'm new in iOS development and my question:
is it possible to create your own table view class that will be subclass of ScrollVeiw and use Delegation pattern as UITableView? thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to create a `UIScrollView` subclass which is not a subclass of `UITableView`?

Comment: @the4kman i want to create own table view class that is "analog" of UITableView and has own basic methods like "numberOfRowsInSection" etc

Comment: Just create a `UITableView` subclass then, as it's already a subclass of `UIScrollView`.